# Почему цикл не выполняется полностью?

Tags: php, парсер

Скажу сразу, это парсинг.

```
require_once(getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT').'/simple_html_dom.php');
for ($i=70000;$i<=70020;$i++){

$html = file_get_html('http://prime-music.net/Media-download-'.$i.'.html');
$a = $html->find('.font12');
$b = $html->find('.download_link');

$_POST['url'] = p(iconv("CP1251", "UTF-8", substr($a[0]->innertext, 20, -4)));
$_POST['title'] = iconv("CP1251", "UTF-8", substr($a[0]->innertext, 20, -4));
$_POST['source'] = $b[0]->href;
$_POST['date'] = time();

$allowed = array("title","source","url","date");
$sql = "INSERT INTO muzic SET ".pdoSet($allowed,$values);
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($values);

$html->clear();
unset($html);
$i++;
}
```

В выборе с диапазоном 100 выполняется лишь 51 раз. Диапазон с 353 выполняется 177 раз. В чем дело?

Comment: Выполнение только половины(!) от ожидаемого числа итераций наводит на мысли о том, что ваше "// что то" изменяет $i. Без минимального кода для воспроизведения проблемы гадать можно долго...

Comment: а зачем еще один i++ внутри?

Comment: `$i++` лишний. Он и без вас инкрементится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теперь понятно что инкремент `$i++` лишний внутри цикла for

Answer (score 1):

Смотрим начало цикла:

```
for ($i=70000;$i<=70020;$i++){
```

И смотрим его конец:

```
$i++;
```

Как и ожидалось, изменение $i происходит **И** в теле цикла тоже